# Generalize regex XML validation

Tags: regex, xml, vb.net

I am looking to make my code better by letting for example `Dim IDNumbers() As String = 'SOMETHING'` instead of writing out the list of strings individually like `{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}`. I want to be able to read all the ID, student name and birthday nodes from my XML file without having to physically go and list them all. I am unsure how to do this If anybody could help with sample code that would be great. The reason for this is that if I modify my code in the file I have to change it in my vb code too.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Globalization
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("student").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                                                            .id = CType(x.Element("ID"), string), _
                                                            .name = CType(x.Element("student_name"), string), _
                                                            .birthday = CType(x.Element("birthday"), string) _
                                                        }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: thanks so much could you please explain this code a little as I am new to vb.net.

Comment: The code is looking for all xml elements "student" and then parsing the three elements 1) ID 2) student_name 3) birthday.

Comment: So I should just put : Dim rgx As New Regex("^[0-9]*$") For Each id In results If rgx.IsMatch(id) = False Then lstErrs.Add("Invalid ID number") End If Next after to validate ??

Comment: NEVER use REGEX TO PARSE HTLM or XML.  It is ok to use regex on the innertext once it is parsed, but never for getting the elements.

Comment: So how do I validate my nodes now ? could you post code example of what you mean by regex on inner text?

Comment: Why do you need to validate if the xml was generated properly?  I always believe with xml that the checking should be done during the generation.  If I was generating data it would be wrong to send out data that was not valid.

Comment: I want to validate that my nodes are correct. eg. ID tag does Not contain any characters only numbers etc. I want to use regex to validate these nodes.I have schema 
                which validates my xml file but Not my nodes. as my program will be reading in big xml files with lots of nodes I am looking for a more generic way to validate my nodes
            so manually having to list them out in the {} format I have above in my original question.

Comment: The schema should be checking the numbers are numeric.

Comment: well I want numeric ranges, birthday structure eg. DD/MM/YY not mm/dd/yy. student name allows for special characters eg. _ in name. I want my regex to validate extra things my schema doesnt

Comment: The read everything as strings instead of integers and datatime.

Comment: When I do that I get an error saying  "value of 'xmlNode' cannot be converted to string"

Comment: Try it with code I just modified which returns strings.

Comment: I have modified the parse but now I have an error stating: "Value of type '<anonymous type: id As String, name As String, birthday As String>' cannot be converted to 'String'." The error is at (id) .... did I call it something wrong or my struture or something? this is the code I have  Dim rgx As New Regex("^[0-9]*$")
            For Each id In results

                If rgx.IsMatch(id) = False Then
                    lstErrs.Add("Invalid ID number")
                End If
            Next

Comment: The birthdays in the file are dd/MM/yyyy not MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: The birthdays have slashes in the, not just digits

Comment: I do not see the code where you are converting the birthday string to a DateTime.